# How to group data in a list by range by displaying the range and quantity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, arraylist, tuples

I am trying to develop a logic that can group an age list into a range defined by a tuple, where the expected result would look like:

```
RANGE, QUANTITY
0-4, 3
5-9, 3
10-14, 1
15-19,2
```

For this, I created the following code:

```
var peoples = new[] {
    new { Id = 1, Age = 2 },
    new { Id = 2, Age = 3 },
    new { Id = 3, Age = 4 },
    new { Id = 4, Age = 6 },
    new { Id = 5, Age = 7 },
    new { Id = 6, Age = 10 },
    new { Id = 7, Age = 16 },
    new { Id = 8, Age = 7 },
    new { Id = 9, Age = 19 },
    new { Id = 10, Age = 23 },
};

var rangesAccepted = new[] { 5, 10, 15, 20, 30 };

var tuples = new List<(int, int)>
{
    (0, 4),
    (5, 9),
    (10, 14),
    (15, 19)
};

var grouped = peoples.
    GroupBy(x => rangesAccepted.FirstOrDefault(r => r >= x.Age))
    .Select(g => new 
    {
        Index = g.Key,
        Quantity = g.Count()
    })
    .OrderBy(g => g.Index)
    .ToList();

var grouped2 = new List<dynamic>();

foreach (var g in grouped)
{
    foreach (var t in tuples)
    {
        if (g.Index >= t.Item1 && t.Item2 <= g.Index)
        {
            grouped2.Add(new
            {
                Range = $"{t.Item1}-{t.Item2}",
                g.Quantity
            });
        }
    }
}
```

At first, I'm working with a list, but the real reason I get these results from the database with the entity framework instead of using a static list. I read other answers, but none of them said how to display the range as shown in the previous example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you would not have duplicates in the `rangesAccepted`, you could use `Array.IndexOf` to find the index of the `Grouping Key`.

```
var result = peoples.GroupBy( x => rangesAccepted.FirstOrDefault( r => r > x.Age ) )
        .Select(x=> 
        new
        { 
            Range = Array.IndexOf(rangesAccepted,x.Key)==0?$"0-{x.Key-1}":$"{rangesAccepted[Array.IndexOf(rangesAccepted,x.Key)-1]}-{rangesAccepted[Array.IndexOf(rangesAccepted,x.Key)]-1}",
            Size = x.ToList().Count
        });
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!